# JSON returns null - and crashes app (check data first)

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

So I am wondering how do I check to see if the return data has title in it before I send it to the following command.

```
guard let urls = URL(string: "https://api.drn1.com.au:9000/nowplaying/\(stationurl)?uuid=\(MusicPlayer.uuid!)") else { return }
              
              
              URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urls) { ( data, _, _) in
             
            
               // Based on the updated structs, you would no
                  // longer be decoding an array
                if(data != nil){
                 
               let podcast = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Nowplayng.self, from: data!)
                   
                  DispatchQueue.main.async{
                      // The array is stored under programs now
                   
                    completion(podcast.data.first!.track)
                    
                  }
                }
              }
       .resume()
    
   }
```

Because according to Crashlytics the following

```
 let podcast = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Nowplayng.self, from: data!)
```

Is causing the app to crash if it has no title which is under

```
podcast.data.first!.track.title
```

The error I am getting from Crashlytics.

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "track", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "title", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file /Users/russellharrower/Apps/vscroll/vscroll/Core/NowPlaying.swift, line 57
```

On further inspection I see that it is saying `stringValue: "data", intValue: nil`

That's great because all I need to do is check that before I send it to the try script?

Comment: The error is telling you that the path `data/array[0]/track/title` is nil. You should not use `try!` if your operation can fail. In this specific case you either need to fix your model to accept optionals or fix your web service to ensure it never sends nil data for that specific path.

Answer (score 0):

The point of `try` is to throw errors if there is a problem. By using `try!` you're promising there cannot be a problem and asking the program to crash if you're wrong. There was a problem, so the program crashed.

Since it's always possible to get bad data from a server, you should never use `try!` on the results. Use do/catch and deal with the error.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urls) { ( data, _, _) in
    if let data = data {
        do {
            let podcast = try JSONDecoder().decode(Nowplayng.self, from: data)
            if let track = podcast.data.first?.track {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(track)
                }
            }
            // But what do you want to do if there isn't a track here? (see below)
        } catch {
            // here, you need to deal with the error. At a minimum you need to
            // log it. But you likely need to modify your completion handler to
            // accept a Result or other way of passing errors back.
        }
    }
    // And here, too. What if there's a web server error response? (see above)
}
```

There's no simple answer here; it depends on what you want the behavior to be. But a good place to start is to change your `completion` function to accept a `Result<Track, Error>` rather than just a Track. That way you can pass failures as well as success.